# Erro ao compilar uma solução em c++ no visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilação, visual-studio-2017

Eu estou tentando compilar uma solução de c ++, mas não está funcionando. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Eu abri uma solução visual studio 2008 no visual studio 2017. Quando dou o build o erro acontece. Eu não encontrei no projeto onde está inclusão desses cabeçalhos (float.h e corecrt_math.h). Alguém teve um problema semelhante?

Estou usando o Windows SDK 10.0.17763.0 e o Visual Studio 2017.

**Error:**

```
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\float.h(311): error C2556: 'double _logb(double)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int _logb(double)'
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(512): note: see declaration of '_logb'
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\float.h(311): error C2371: '_logb': redefinition; different basic types
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(512): note: see declaration of '_logb'
```

**corecrt_math.h:**

```
_Check_return_ _ACRTIMP int       __cdecl ilogb(_In_ double _X);
```

**float.h:**

```
_Check_return_ _ACRTIMP double __cdecl _logb(_In_ double _X);
```

Comment: reescreva sua pergunta em português...este site *pt*.stack.overflow.com só aceita perguntas em português

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em C++ é ilegal fazer overloading de duas funcões que diferem apenas pelo tipo de retorno.

```
_Check_return_ _ACRTIMP int    __cdecl ilogb(_In_ double _X);
_Check_return_ _ACRTIMP double __cdecl _logb(_In_ double _X);
```

A primeira coisa a fazer é retirar o include "corecrt_math.h" que parece ser um include interno do C++ da Microsoft, e ver se o projeto compila.

Se isto não funcionar, você vai ter que descobrir quais fontes dependem deste include "corecrt_math.h", e fazer a compilação à parte destes fontes.

Comment: Comecei a comentar os #includes um por um e compilar o arquivo, até encontrar os cabeçalhos que estavam gerando o problema. O dificil é encontrar o cabeçalho já que eu não estava incluindo explicitamente float.h e corecrt_math.h. Como você disse deve ser algo interno do C++ da Microsoft.